# Как проверить JSON на наличие определённых строк?

Tags: javascript, json

Как проверить на наличие в JSON определённых строк, вот например:

```
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Weissgold-Verlobungsring mit Diamanten",
        "image": "/images/content/white-gold1.jpg",
        "oldprice": "14 500 €",
        "newprice": "16 100 €",
        "discount": "-10%"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Gold-Verlobungsring mit Diamanten",
        "image": "/images/content/white-gold2.jpg",
        "oldprice": "110 500 €",
        "newprice": "16 100 €",
        "hit": "hit"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Ring zur Verlobung mit Diamanten",
        "image": "/images/content/white-gold3.jpg",
        "oldprice": "110 500 €",
        "newprice": "16 100 €",
        "new": "new"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Ring zur Verlobung mit Diamanten",
        "image": "/images/content/white-gold1.jpg",
        "oldprice": "110 500 €",
        "newprice": "16 100 €"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Ring zur Verlobung mit Diamanten",
        "image": "/images/content/white-gold3.jpg",
        "oldprice": "110 500 €",
        "hit": "hit"
    }
```

Есть discount, как проверить на его наличие?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.b-pagination__link--more').click(function(){                    // вешаем на клик
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/product.json',
        //url: '/ajax/review.php',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            if (json['product'].length > 0) {
                var product = json['product'];
                $.each(product, function (id, data) {
                    // console.log()
                    var html = '<a href="#"  data-product-id="' + data.id + '" title="" class="b-list-product__item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">\
                                    <div class="b-list-product__link">\
                                        <div class="b-list-product__background"></div>\
                                        <div class="b-list-product__quick-preview">\
                                            <span class="b-button-color b-list-product__link-preview">Übersicht</span>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                    <img src="' + data.image + '" alt="" title="" class="b-list-product__image">\
                                    <p class="b-list-product__info">' + data.name + '</p>\
                                    <p class="b-list-product__price">' + data.newprice + '</p>\
                                    <div class="b-list-product__old-price">\
                                        <p class="b-list-product__old">' + data.oldprice + '</p>';
                    if (parseInt(data.discount) > 0) {
                    html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product">' + data.discount + '</div>';
                    }

                    html += '</div>\
                                </a>';
                    $('.b-list-product__item:last-child').before(html).parent('.b-list-product--catalog');
                });
            }
        }
    });
 })
});
```

Попробовал вот такой вариант

```
if (parseInt(data.discount) > 0) {
  html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product">' + data.discount +</div>';
}
```

Но не работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty),

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty('discount')) {
  html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product">' + data.discount + '</div>';
};
if (data.hasOwnProperty('hit')) {
  html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product b-sale__hit">' + data.hit + '</div>';
};
if (data.hasOwnProperty('new')) {
  html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product b-sale__new">' + data.new + '</div>';
};
```

Comment: ну, только сначала JSON надо распарсить

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев , Согласен, но вопрос был относительно js и json и относился к тому как проверить наличие ключа в объекте, а не как распарсить полученные json данные по объектам и узнать, в каких объектах есть такие ключи

Comment: обновил вопрос) конечно parseInt неверно, он число вроде как возвращает

Comment: А если попробовать использовать предложенный код? `if(data.hasOwnProperty('discount')){....}`

Comment: не работает. if (product.hasOwnProperty('discount') > 0) {
                        html += '<div class="b-sale b-sale--list-product">' + data.discount + '</div>';
                        } не выводит HTML

Comment: я предлагал не это, вы должны использовать это уже внутри цикла `$.each` когда получили один из объектов массива объектов `product`, Если бы вы прочитали ссылку которую я привел, то поняли бы что метод hasOwnProperty предназначен для проверки существования ключа, соответственно вы можете узнать есть или нет ключ `discount` в массиве ключей `data` и уже если есть тогда выводить его значение через `parseInt()`

Comment: Да все верно, почему в консоли ругается на {   Тут как-то можно в личку писать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37704/discussion-between-drtvader-and-lamerxaker).